# How do I determine if a given function is entire?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the three functions $\displaystyle e^{\frac{r}{\ln r}}$, $\displaystyle e^r$, and $\displaystyle e^{r\ln r}$, where $r = |z|$. Note that these are not constant functions.

Can someone explain to me why all these three functions are not entire, especially the second one?

Comment: These functions are not differentiable in $z$.

Comment: Are these supposed to be constant functions?

Comment: If they're function of $r$, they're obviously not entire, since you define them only for $r>0$.

Comment: @Travis: They are not constant functions.

Answer (score 3):

If the second function were entire, then it would satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations for all $z$. Let $z=x+iy$ so that $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Now $e^r = e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. Now check the Cauchy Riemann equations. Note that in this case $f(z) = e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} + i \cdot 0$.

A similar approach will work for the other problems as well.

Comment: For convenience, let $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u(x,y)=e^{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and $v(x,y)=0$. If $f(z)$ were entire, then we would have that $f^{\prime}(z)$ exists at an arbitrary point $z_0=x_0+iy_0$. At such a point, the Cauchy-Riemann equations would also have to hold, i.e. $u_x=v_y$ and $u_y=-v_x$. For the function $e^r$, it is clear that $\frac{x}{|z|}e^{|z|}=u_x\neq v_y=0$ and $\frac{y}{|z|}e^{|z|}=u_y\neq -v_x=0$. Hence, the function $e^{|z|}$ is not entire.

Comment: Yep that's the idea. @cantor_paradise

Answer (score 1):

For any entire function $f,$ $f$ is either constant or $f(\mathbb C)$ is open in $\mathbb C.$ Your functions are not constant, and in all cases $f(\mathbb C)\subset \mathbb R,$ hence $f(\mathbb C)$ cannot be open, so none of them can be entire.